# how to append some text before each matched lines

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I need to append two words before each match lines -

have following text file -

demo.txt -

```
Good
70 80 75 77 82
Best
Fail
34 32 30 24 29
```

What I am looking for is, if it find Good it should append 2 words before it like below -
Good

```
(sysdate) Good 70 80 75 77 82
```

and if no record found, should not do anything like with Best record as there's no record so no need to append (sysdate) Best in front of it's line.

but trick here is, it should check two conditions, first status as Good, Best or Fail status from file and second if associate record is blank then no need to append anything.

below is short code of shell script -

```
#!/bin/bash

TIME=`date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`
log="demo.txt"

for line in $log
   do
     if $line eq 'Good'; then
          sed "/$line/!p s/[[:space:]]\+$//g" $log | sed "s/^/$TIME,Good /g" $log | sed 's/ /,/g' $log > demo.csv
     elif $line eq 'Best'; then
          sed "/$line/!p s/[[:space:]]\+$//g" $log | sed "s/^/$TIME,Best /g"   $log | sed 's/ /,/g' $log > demo.csv
     else
          sed "/$line/!p s/[[:space:]]\+$//g" $log | sed "s/^/$TIME,Fail /g" $log | sed 's/ /,/g' $log > demo.csv
     fi
done
```

Note :- looking for below output to csv file -

demo.csv -

```
Good
(sysdate),Good,70,80,75,77,82
Best
Fail
(sysdate),Fail,34,32,30,24,29
```

Comment: better to emphasize that  `(sysdate)` in sample output is actually value returned by `date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`.. also point out what went wrong with your attempt... one issue easy to spot is that `> demo.csv` will create a new file every time...

Comment: yes, good catch, should be ">>" from second conditions. I tried with Awk and Sed but not getting output as expected so gave (base) code,, above sed not giving output as expected so I am looking for what to use awk, sed or script to achieve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Input**

```
$ cat demo.txt
Good
70 80 75 77 82
Best
Fail
34 32 30 24 29
```

**Output**

```
$ awk -v OFS="," 'NF==1{ print; s=$0; next}{$1=$1; print "(sysdate)",s,$0}' demo.txt
Good
(sysdate),Good,70,80,75,77,82
Best
Fail
(sysdate),Fail,34,32,30,24,29
```

**With datetime**

```
$ awk -v t="$(date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')" -v OFS="," 'NF==1{ print; s=$0; next}{$1=$1; print t,s,$0}' demo.txt
Good
2017-03-15 17:12:16,Good,70,80,75,77,82
Best
Fail
2017-03-15 17:12:16,Fail,34,32,30,24,29
```

With [gawk](/questions/tagged/gawk)

```
$ awk -v OFS="," 'BEGIN{t=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",systime())}NF==1{ print; s=$0; next}{$1=$1; print t,s,$0}' demo.txt
Good
2017-03-15 17:18:50,Good,70,80,75,77,82
Best
Fail
2017-03-15 17:18:50,Fail,34,32,30,24,29
```

**Explanation**

```
awk -v OFS="," '                  # call awk set o/p field separator as comma
      BEGIN{                      # Begin block here we save system datetime in variable t and is gwak specific
             t=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",systime())
      }
     NF==1{                       # if no of fields/columns is equal to 1 then
               print;             # print current record/line/row
               s=$0;              # save current line in variable s
               next               # stop processing go to next line
      }
      {
               $1=$1;             # record recompilation 
                                  # since you need comma as separator between fields in o/p,  
                                  # you can also do $2=$2
                                  # assigning any value to any field ($1, etc.) 
                                  # causes record recompilation
               print t,s,$0       # print variable t, s and current line
      }' demo.txt
```

Comment: you are gawkanius, but can you explain steps which you mentioned.. also there was just little change with input file after every associate record there's one '\n' like (Good
2017-03-15 17:18:50,Good,70,80,75,77,82 \n Best) but no problem I removed extra line from my input file but please **explain steps**

Comment: @Kshitij8097: added explanation, to skip blank line just replace `{$1=$1; print t,s,$0}` with `NF{$1=$1; print t,s,$0}`

Comment: @akshay-hedge +1 , thanks but if you know can we do it with sed or shell script just for additional info.

Comment: @Kshitij8097: In current context `awk` fits well, and its short also.

Comment: Hi Akshay, is it possible to re-format output like below -
2017-03-15 17:18:50,Good,70,80,75,77,82\n
2017-03-15 17:18:50,Fail,34,32,30,24,29

(no need of Good,Best and Fail to show in output file)

Comment: no issue, solved, just removed print and found as expected output..
'BEGIN{t=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",systime())}NF==1{s=$0; next}NF{$1=$1; print t,s,$0}